# image manipulation library

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, tesseract

I need a library for mostly color manipulation, I want to make a image become black and white, and augment the contrast, so that Tesseract (Google OCR library) can read better the images that I throw at it.

Or if someone has a better idea on how to improve Tesseract results, I am all for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try OpenCV

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencv/

Or imagemagick

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php

or CImg, probably the easiest to use: no install it's just a header file.

If you do not want to use a big library you can code the algorithm yourself:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140825114946/http://bobpowell.net/image_contrast.aspx

Comment: Magick++ is useful to do that. You won't find a library that only changes the contrast.